# Expect not working using -c arguments

Tags: linux, unix, scp, expect

So I have an expect script like this that works:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn scp me@myserver.com:* .
expect {
password: {send "mypassword"; exp_continue}
}
```

Based on the man page for expect, I think I should be able to do this instead from the command line to accomplish the same thing

```
expect -c "spawn scp me@myserver.com:* ." -c "expect {password: {send \"mypassword\\r\"; exp_continue}}"
```

But this returns to the terminal

```
spawn scp me@myserver.com:* .
me@myserver.com's password:
```

and then after a few seconds gives up without an error message and never does anything.

**Note**

Yes, I'm well aware that I should not do this with scp and should instead use keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain, but I suspect the multiple `-c` arguments are the problem. You can use a here-doc to pass the script on stdin:

```
expect <<'END'
spawn scp me@myserver.com:* .
expect {
password: {send "mypassword"; exp_continue}
}
END
```

The single quotes around the first `'END'` will quote the whole document.

Comment: i did essentially this, but used echo to pipe into expect instead